# TestNG tests multiple ids (as an array) in a single annotation of Java

Tags: java, testing, annotations, automated-tests, testng

I have a TestInfo interface for annotating TestNG tests as below:

```
public @interface TestInfo {

    /**
     * Test case ID
     */
    public String[] id();

    boolean deploy() default true;

}
```

In above case, id() is an array of String type (String[ ]). Now my testng tests look like this for example:

```
@TestInfo(id={"C9114", "C9115"})
@Test 
public class testTrial() {
...something
}
```

How do I read this annotation array and process each of these `ids` in a for loop. For instance, I could think of approach like `get the test method` then annotation and check for each id as shown below...

```
Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        Method method = result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();
        TestInfo annotation = method.getAnnotation(TestInfo.class);
        int status = 0;
        try {
            if (annotation!=null) {

            for(;;/*each id*/){     

                    map.put("id",annotation.id().substring(1));

                    switch (status) {
                    case ITestResult.SUCCESS:
                        map.put("result", STATUS.PASSED.getValue());
                    case ITestResult.FAILURE:
                        map.put("result", STATUS.AUTO_FAIL.getValue());
                    case ITestResult.SKIP:
                        map.put("result", STATUS.AUTO_SKIPPED.getValue());
                    default:
                        map.put("result", STATUS.UNTESTED.getValue());
                    }
                    ApiIntegration.addTestResult(map);

            }
}
```

As I am trying to store the id and result of that id associated with test...I would like to know what is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly the question is on data structure, isn't it?

In that case you can use Guava `com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap`

```
    ListMultimap<String, String> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    for (String id : annotation.ids()) {
        map.put(ITestResult.SUCCESS, id);
    }

    // getting all passed
    List<String> passedTestIds = map.get(ITestResult.SUCCESS);
```